# Why does Intelij Idea let us make incorrect pair equals()-hashcode() by generator?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, equals, hashcode

There is a generator in `IntelliJ` IDEA. You press `Alt`+`Ins`, choose 'equal and `hashCode`' and a constructors opens. You can choose fields for equals and then you can choose fields for `hashCode()`. Why can we choose different field sets? Isn't it contradicted to equals-hashCode contracts?

Comment: Not necessarily. Equal objects must have the same hashcode, that doesn't mean that both equals and the hashcode must be based on the same fields.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't really allow you to choose different field sets, it allows you to pick a subset of the fields for `equals`, to use for `hashCode`.
While this will probably lead to a poorer hash code since this will cause more hash collisions, it will technically still be correct. Note that the requirement is just that equal objects have equal hash codes, not that equal hash codes must be from equal objects. The latter would be impossible to achieve for classes that can have more different instances than there are `int`s (e.g. `java.lang.Long`).

There may be good motivations to use a suboptimal hash for collisions if calculating the best hash for collisions would be too expensive, compared to just dealing with the collision.

Answer (score 0):

As per Java Doc of Object Class -

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the {@code hashCode}
>       method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the
>       general contract for the {@code hashCode} method, which states
>       that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

By default **equals** method returns **true** for inputs **referring** to **same object instance**. An overridden **equals** might return **true** for completely different objects even (even the object with different field values) which totally depends on your **implementation**.

> The contract enforces that if your **equals** logic is determining two
>   different object as same, your **hashcode** method should return the same
>   value for those two objects.

This does not mean that you should be using the same fields for **hashcode** also. This is all what you should be taking care of while overriding these functions.